# HTML Navbar is under slideshow (not on screen) How to force it to bottom of screen without making it sticky or using Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, nav

The navbar on the website is appearing below a js slideshow and cannot get the navbar to appear in front of it at the bottom of the page. I cannot use the css sticky item as I need the navbar to move to the top of the screen and stay there when the user scrolls down.

I have tried putting the slideshow container to be relative and increase the z-index of the navbar however this does nothing.

```html
<header>
        <div class="slideshow-container">
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x1080" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x1080" style="width:100%">
            </div>
            <div class="mySlides fade">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/1900x1080" style="width:100%">
            </div>
        </div>
        <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn">About</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="about.html">About us</a>
                <a href="nco-profile.html">NCO Profiles</a>
                <a href="co-profile.html">CO profiles</a>
                </div>
            </div>
                <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="joinInfo.html">Joining Info</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link " href="calendar.html">Calendar</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="forms.html">Forms</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="courses.html">Courses</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="courses.html">Support Committee</a>
                </li>
          </ul>
        </div>  
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

```css
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #083867;
    font-family: Arial;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    bottom: 0;
}
.slideshow-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The navbar is supposed to be on top of the slideshow at the bottom with the slideshow running in the background, but the slideshow is above the navbar.

Comment: create a fiddle and upload working code with bootstrap link.

Comment: Can you post the complete working code? Did you try absolute positioning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding position `fixed`, `absolute`, or `relative` to the navbar and then giving it a z-index greater than 1.

Comment: `absolute` works to an extent. The navbar is now on the screen to start with, however, when you scroll down the navbar jumps from being on top of the slideshow to being underneath after a certain point. How would you solve this issue?